# Visual Studio 2017 cannot find some files

Tags: visual-studio, nvidia

I have Visual Studio 2017, Community edition; whenever I start my computer, I recieve from it four warning messages of missing files: extension.vsxmanifest, Nvda.UnifiedDebugger.Package.pkgdef, Nvda.Vsip.Debugger.Device.dll.pkgdef and Nvda.Vsip.Net.dll.pkgdef.
I get that there is some problem with some NVIDIA packages (I recently installed the CUDA Toolkit), but how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the visual studio with administrator privillage (Run As Administrator) for one time after CUDA toolkit installation (this worked for me).

Comment: This would make a better comment as it does not answer the question.